# Role based access control to WSO Message Broker Hierarchical Topic

Tags: jms, wso2, publish-subscribe, wso2-esb

I've recently started experimenting with a Message exchange between WSO2 ESB's via WSO2's MB for a requirement. Created a JMS sender Proxy Service which concatenates endpoint URL based on SOAP Input (used Header property and defaultEndpoint).

On Message Broker:

Have set up a  Hierarchical topic as

Root|
   Node1
   Node2
With 3 users and their specific roles as Root, Node1, Node2. Requirement is Node 1 should be able to subscribe for both Node 1 and Root, Similarly for Node2, Only Node2 and Root.
The problem is When creating a proxy service subscriber can only set it to subscribe one Node only (Root or Node1 or Node2). Tried setting destination as Root.# but then All Nodes are subscribed (even when Node USer is not set to Subscribe the other based on Role based Topic access). Following is the code for subscriber

```
enter code here

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="Subscriber_Node2"
   transports="jms"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <log level="full"/>
     <log level="custom" separator="###">
        <property name="STATE"
                  value="**************** RECEIVED AT Node 2 ***************"/>
     </log>
     <drop/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence/>
  <faultSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured"/>
        <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
        <property name="code" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
        <property name="detail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
        <property name="exception" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
     </log>
  </faultSequence>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
   <rules>
     <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
     <default>application/xml</default>
  </rules>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">  
   org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
  </parameter> 
  <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">
   Store2TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
  <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">
   repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">topic</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">HQ.Store_2</parameter>
  <description/>
  </proxy>
```

jndi.properties:

```
  connectionfactory.Node1TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://Node1:Node1@clientID/carbon?    
   brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5680'
   connectionfactory.Node2TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://Node2:Node2@clientID/carbon?    
   brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5680'
   connectionfactory.RootTopicConnectionFactory = amqp://Root1:Root1@clientID/carbon?  
   brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5680'

   topic.Root = Root
   topic.Root.Node1 = Root.Node1
```

### topic.Root.Node2 = Root.Node2

Is there a way a Subscriber can subscribe to Multiple Topics in a hierrarchy and its access be controlled by User and Role?